# Hbase Scala connectivity issue in Cloudera Quick start VM CDH5.8.0

Tags: scala, hbase, apache-zookeeper, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am trying to connect HBase from a Scala code but getting below error.

```
17/03/28 11:40:53 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=30, retries=35, started=450502 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=  
17/03/28 11:41:13 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=31, retries=35, started=470659 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=  
17/03/28 11:41:33 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=32, retries=35, started=490824 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=  
17/03/28 11:41:53 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=33, retries=35, started=510834 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=  
17/03/28 11:42:13 INFO client.RpcRetryingCaller: Call exception, tries=34, retries=35, started=530956 ms ago, cancelled=false, msg=  
[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=35, exceptions:  
[error] Tue Mar 28 11:33:22 PDT 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490726002560, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper  
[error] Tue Mar 28 11:33:23 PDT 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490726002560, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper  
[error] Tue Mar 28 11:33:23 PDT 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490726002560, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper  
[error] Tue Mar 28 11:33:24 PDT 2017, RpcRetryingCaller{globalStartTime=1490726002560, pause=100, retries=35}, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper  
.  
.  
.  
.  
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTables(HBaseAdmin.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTables(HBaseAdmin.java:411)
    at Hi$.main(hw.scala:12)
    at Hi.main(hw.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionManager.java:1737)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MasterCallable.prepare(MasterCallable.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTables(HBaseAdmin.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTables(HBaseAdmin.java:411)
    at Hi$.main(hw.scala:12)
    at Hi.main(hw.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$BlockingStub.isMasterRunning(MasterProtos.java:58383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.isMasterRunning(ConnectionManager.java:1591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStubNoRetries(ConnectionManager.java:1529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1551)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionManager.java:1737)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MasterCallable.prepare(MasterCallable.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTables(HBaseAdmin.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTables(HBaseAdmin.java:411)
    at Hi$.main(hw.scala:12)
    at Hi.main(hw.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/net/SocketInputWrapper
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.createConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.getConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:1316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$BlockingStub.isMasterRunning(MasterProtos.java:58383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.isMasterRunning(ConnectionManager.java:1591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStubNoRetries(ConnectionManager.java:1529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1551)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionManager.java:1737)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MasterCallable.prepare(MasterCallable.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTables(HBaseAdmin.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTables(HBaseAdmin.java:411)
    at Hi$.main(hw.scala:12)
    at Hi.main(hw.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketInputWrapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.createConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.getConnection(RpcClientImpl.java:1316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:331)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$BlockingStub.isMasterRunning(MasterProtos.java:58383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.isMasterRunning(ConnectionManager.java:1591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStubNoRetries(ConnectionManager.java:1529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1551)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionManager.java:1737)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MasterCallable.prepare(MasterCallable.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTables(HBaseAdmin.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.listTables(HBaseAdmin.java:411)
    at Hi$.main(hw.scala:12)
    at Hi.main(hw.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
17/03/28 07:56:55 ERROR zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Event thread exiting due to interruption
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2052)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:494)
17/03/28 07:56:55 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 544 s, completed Mar 28, 2017 7:56:56 AM
```

•   Host OS is Windows 7 with 8 GB RAM and 64 bit arch. Intel core i5.
•   I am using Cloudera Quick start VM CDH 5.8.0. on my Wndows.
•   VM is using 6GB RAM, 2 processors & 64 GB Harddisk.
•   Services running in Cloudera Manager:

```
    Hbase  
    HDFS  
    YARN  
    Zookeeper  
    Key-Value Indexer
```

•   Services stopped in Cloudera Manager:

```
    Hive
    Hue
    Impala
    Oozie
    Solar
    Spark
    Sqoop 1 Client
    Sqoop 2
```

•   Hbase version 1.2.0-cdh5.8.0
•   My client code is in VM only.
•   Created the sbt project.
•   I referred this url https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#scala  for Hbase connectivity with Scala.
•   Setting the **CLASSPATH**. I did't mention the "/path/to/scala-library.jar" in the CLASSPATH as mentiond in the link.

```
$ export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:/usr/lib/hbase/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64
```

•   Project root directory = /home/cloudera/Desktop/play-sbt-project
•   My /home/cloudera/Desktop/play-sbt-project/**build.sbt** looks like this. I changed the dependent library version as per my environment. I added few more dependencies like "hbase-client", "hbase-common" & "hbase-server" as part of error troubleshoot but still didn't got success.

```
name := "play-sbt-project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.2"
resolvers += "Apache HBase" at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases"
resolvers += "Thrift" at "http://people.apache.org/~rawson/repo/"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "1.2.1",
"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "1.2.0",
"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.2.0",
"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.2.0",
"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.2.0"
)
```

•   My main code for Hbase connectivity /home/cloudera/Desktop/play-sbt-project/src/main/scala/pw.scala looks like this

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{ConnectionFactory,HBaseAdmin,HTable,Put,Get}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

object Hi {
def main(args: Array[String]) = {
println("Hi!")
val conf = new HBaseConfiguration()
val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
val admin = connection.getAdmin();

// list the tables
val listtables=admin.listTables()
listtables.foreach(println)
}
}
```

•   My /etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--Autogenerated by Cloudera Manager-->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.replication</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.write.buffer</name>
    <value>2097152</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.pause</name>
    <value>100</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.retries.number</name>
    <value>35</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.scanner.caching</name>
    <value>100</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize</name>
    <value>10485760</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.ipc.client.allowsInterrupt</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.primaryCallTimeout.get</name>
    <value>10</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.primaryCallTimeout.multiget</name>
    <value>10</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.SecureBulkLoadEndpoint</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.thrift.http</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.thrift.support.proxyuser</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name>
    <value>60000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.snapshot.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.snapshot.master.timeoutMillis</name>
    <value>60000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.snapshot.region.timeout</name>
    <value>60000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.snapshot.master.timeout.millis</name>
    <value>60000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.security.authentication</name>
    <value>simple</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rpc.protection</name>
    <value>authentication</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>zookeeper.session.timeout</name>
    <value>60000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.rootserver</name>
    <value>root-region-server</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <!-- <value>quickstart.cloudera</value> -->
    <value>127.0.0.1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rest.ssl.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I googled alot to solve this issue but didn't got sucess. In the process of solving this issue I have done below changes:
•   Changed the Dependent libraries version in build.sbt file as per my environment
•   Added few more dependent libraries "hbase-client", "hbase-common" & "hbase-server".
•   Chaned the "hbase.zookeeper.quorum" value from "quickstart.cloudera" to "127.0.0.1" in "hbase-site.xml" file.

Please help me solving this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Is that really the version of `hadoop-core` you are using?  Hadoop versions are not the same as HBase versions.  CDH5.8 is based on Hadoop 2.6.

Comment: @Joe Pallas , Thanks for the comment. I solved the issue. `hadoop-core` and compatible jar dependency versions was one of the changes which I have done along with some code changes. I am posting my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue. There are following changes need to be done:

1. Change "hadoop-core" to "hadoop-common" inside build.sbt file. Since in latest CDH versions 'hadoop-core' is only supported by code running for MapReduce 1.
2. Change all the dependecy version as per cloudera 5.8.0 compatibility in build.sbt. Updated **build.sbt** looks like this:

   ```
   name := "play-sbt-project"  
   version := "1.0"  
   scalaVersion := "2.10.2"  
   resolvers += "Thrift" at "http://people.apache.org/~rawson/repo/"  
   resolvers += "Cloudera Repository" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/"  

   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(  
    "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.6.0-cdh5.8.0",  
    "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "1.2.0-cdh5.8.0",  
    "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.2.0-cdh5.8.0",  
    "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.2.0-cdh5.8.0",  
    "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.2.0-cdh5.8.0"  
   )
   ```
3. HBaseConfiguration() class is depricated. Instead use create() method. Also I changed some logic in the main code. Earlier I was getting the tables present in HBase (Since this was giving some issues so I dropped this but I will try this next time), Since my moto is to establish Scala to HBase connectivity so now I am trying to insert new row to the already existing HBase table. New code looks like this:

   ```
   package main.scala

   import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration  
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{ConnectionFactory,HTable,Put}  
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes  

   object Hi {  

    def main(args: Array[String]) = {  
    println("Hi!")  
    val conf:Configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create()  
    val table:HTable = new HTable(conf, "emp1")  
    val put1:Put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("row1"))  
    put1.add(Bytes.toBytes("personal_data"),Bytes.toBytes("qual1"),Bytes.toBytes("val1"))  
    table.put(put1)  
    println("Success")  
    }  
   }
   ```